# DKIM : Signature header exists but is not valid

Tags: linux, email, nginx, smtp

I have configured Postfix with SPF and DKIM but all emails are marked as spam.

Here is my domain.db (I use bind9) :

```
...
mail._domainkey IN      TXT     ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=ABCD" )
```

I verify with :

```
host -t TXT mail._domainkey.domain.com
```

I receive (OK) :

```
mail._domainkey.domain.com descriptive text "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; " "p=ABCD"
```

I've checked also what could be the problem on [email-tester.com](http://email-tester.com), and I get 10/10, DKIM seems also correctly installed.

But when I check the content of an email, I see :

```
...
dkim:pass
dkim:pass
SPF:pass
...
X-Spam-Report: 
* -0.0 NO_RELAYS Informational: message was not relayed via SMTP
* -0.0 NO_RECEIVED Informational: message has no Received headers
*  0.0 T_DKIM_INVALID DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid

X-Spam-Status: No, score=0.0 required=5.0 tests=NO_RECEIVED,NO_RELAYS,
T_DKIM_INVALID autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
```

Any idea ?

----- UPDATE -------

After adding in master.cf :

```
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
```

Here is the new email content :

```
...
dkim:pass   (now there is only one: OK)
spf:pass 
...
X-Spam-Report: 
* -1.0 ALL_TRUSTED Passed through trusted hosts only via SMTP

X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.0 required=5.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED autolearn=ham
autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
```

which seems better, but the email is still marked as spam, grrr

Comment: I think your DKIM is using two strings when it should be using 1, based on what you received.  Every DKIM Validator have quirks about them, send an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` - They run your DKIM through 4 different validators.

Comment: I tried to send an email to this address, for present moment I didn't receive sthg, strange.. And how do you know that there is maybe 2 DKIM ? indeed you're right, I see 2 lines : dkim=pass (above SPF:pass), is it possible to remove one DKIM?

Comment: @henry I tried to change DKIM1 to DKIM and now I get : dkim=neutral (bad version), grr, thank you for your help henry..

Comment: Remove the v=dkim1 all together it's not needed.  Are you sure you sent an email to the right place? Also if you can share your domain key location, I can see if it's correct syntax wise.

Comment: @henry I tried again to send an email, successfully sent (250 OK) but I receive nothing..:( Here is the domain : http://www.luckeo.fr ps : I removed & tried to generate a new key (was named DKIM1), updated then files, restarted all services, and now host -t still show DKIM instead of DKIM1, grr, I think there is a serious problem..

Comment: @henry I suddently got the email from Unlock the inbox, just to confirm that you're right there are 2 DKIM (2 signatures), is it possible to remove one? thank you henry..

Comment: Take a look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/475416/is-there-a-reason-why-dkim-signs-every-mail-twice

Comment: After you fix that, run a new test and post the link it gives you. So I can see what you're seeing.

Comment: @henry, thank you henry, I added "-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters" in master.cf (from your link) and now there is 1 DKIM but the email is still marked as spam, grr, I've updated the question with the new content of the email..

Comment: Did you run a new test at `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com`?  I need to see the results of that test to help out, it gives you a shareable link.

Comment: here is the link : https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/MyksRpIo4Pg=/

Comment: That's odd that your SPF Record is not being found, I can see it just fine. I think you have an extra space at the END of it. Remove it please, lets see if that gets things working.

Comment: yes strange with this SPF, I tried also with http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3aluckeo.fr&run=toolpage and evthg seems okay, grr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on with your SPF record.

Go to this link and change the DNS Server to `Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8)

```
https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnstools/spf/luckeo.fr/
```

The results of your SPF will be `v=spf a mx ip4:176.58.101.240 ~all`

Now change it to DNS Advantage (156.154.70.1)

The results of your SPF will be `v=spf1 a mx ip4:176.58.101.240 ~all`

Notice the difference `v=spf` vs `v=spf1`

So your DNS hasn't propagated yet and depending on how the receiving email server looks up your DNS Records you're running into issues. Wait 24 hours and if you're still having issues, reply back.

Comment: here is the last link : https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/SUcC6jd9RyY=/  SPF seems to be okay now, but emails are still marked as spam :(

Answer (score 3):

A working SPD DKIM config does not necessarily lead it to not beeing categorized as spam.

I had to find that out escpecially from virtual hosters or cloud server/mail providers the ip ranges of them have a generally bad reputation which means even without sending spam before from the url and fresh DKIM SPF ect. the mails still go directly to junk (for example in office 365 which have a very strict unforgetting spam filter) because the IP belongs to a range that is generally marked with a bad reputation, or some spammer used the IP in the past...

(I did my testing with a custom DigitalOcean server postfix/opendkim and a free Mailgun account, Mailgun seems to offer dedicated IPs hopefuly without a ba drep as it seems in some blog posts)

Of course this is very annoying but of course also Marketing mail from SPFed and DKIMed servers get marked as Spam therefore big providers seem to go to the IP level ...  I also read that especially office365 has some  system that takes user feedback into account and assigns the negative spam markts back down till the IP.